# deploy rails app using capistrano or aws opsworks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, twilio

I have written a twilio app that I would like to deploy on AWS. This is my first time and I find two options which I would like ask about. 
Should I deploy my app to aws using

1) AWS Opsworks? [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome.html#welcome-start) or

2) Capistrano [Link](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/)

Hoping to simply get some direction, I am very new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend Opsworks over Capistrano. I used to use Capistrano for deployment, then switched to OpsWorks and never looked back.

The learning curve for OpsWorks is steeper and you should familiarize yourself with Chef, however, there are many benefits:

- Better environment management
- Ability to provision and scale when necessary
- Better integration with the AWS toolset (ELB, Certificates)
- Improved deploy logging
- Chef/Opsworks is an external dependency and doesn't require extra gems and config within your application itself.
- Improved monitoring and notifications with cloudwatch

The only real drawback to Opsworks/Chef is additional complexity and learning curve, though the benefits are well worth it.

I've also found deployment to be more stable on OpsWorks compared to Capistrano and much easier to manage. In the event of a failed deploy it's also much easier to track and diagnose issues if they do happen.

Comment: thank you anthony. For climbing the learning curve in opsworks, would you recommend any particular learning material? Or is the documentation from amazon on aws sufficient?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. For me it was a combination of trial and error and reading the AWS docs.

Comment: got it, wish I had something more streamlined to follow, but will submit to the inevitable trial and error process